# Handling multiple forms on the same Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

Has anyone found a trick for handling multiple forms on a Razor Page?

My page has two forms, each with a corresponding model that is decorated with a `BindProperty` attribute.

```
[BindProperty]
public TripDetailsUpdateDto UpdateTrip { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public TripNoteUpdateDto UpdateNote { get; set; }
```

The problem is that, although either one works fine on its own, having both of them causes `ModelState.IsValid` to return false. Both models are combined and when one model is submitted, the properties of the other model haven't been set.

Surely I'm not the first to struggle with this. Is there a way to deal with this case without writing manual code to remove the unused items from `ModelState`?

Comment: Are both forms submitting to the same action?

Comment: @madreflection: No, I'm using page handlers and each form posts to it's own page handler.

Comment: Ah. Didn't notice the razor-pages tag. Page handlers still use the same page model. If you were using MVC, you would submit each one to a different action method with its own model parameter and the ModelState would not include unrelated inputs.

Comment: You can use the `asp-page-handler` or `formaction` attribute in each button to specify a different action. You can bind elements to object properties, so *maybe* you can combine both features to handle multiple forms. I think I did this a while ago but I can't remember exactly what I did

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: As mentioned, I'm already using a page handler. Please see my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

So, as suggested, the problem is that every property of every model decorated with the `[BindProperty]` is combined into the `ModelState`.

To resolve the issue, first remove all `[BindProperty]` attributes.

Then bind to your values with a parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateNoteAsync(int noteId, TripNoteUpdateDto updateNote)
{
    // ...
}
```

Notes:

1. You can still have the original model members (in my case, `UpdateTrip` and `UpdateNote`). You can still reference them from your markup. This allows your markup to consider validation attributes, and also lets you specify default values.
2. If your markup references your original model members, your model argument must have the same name in order to match.